# На почте при восстановлении пароля есть поле PASSWORD, но нет самого пароля

Tags: php, битрикс

В файле init.php добавил код. При восстановлении пароля, на мою почту действительно приходит поле PASSWORD, но оно без пароля. Что не так?

```
\Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandlerCompatible( 

    'main', 

    'OnBeforeUserAdd', 

    '\Partner\SendPassword::onBeforeUserAddUpdate'

); 



\Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandlerCompatible( 

    'main', 

    'OnBeforeUserUpdate', 

    '\Partner\SendPassword::onBeforeUserAddUpdate'

); 



\Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandlerCompatible( 

    'main', 

    'OnAfterUserAdd', 

    '\Partner\SendPassword::onAfterUserAdd'

); 



\Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandlerCompatible( 

    'main', 

    'OnAfterUserUpdate', 

    '\Partner\SendPassword::onAfterUserUpdate'

); 



\Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandlerCompatible( 

    'main', 

    'OnBeforeEventAdd', 

    '\Partner\SendPassword::onBeforeEventAdd'

); 
\Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandlerCompatible( 

    'main', 

    'OnBeforeUserChangePassword', 

    '\Partner\SendPassword::onBeforeUserChangePassword'

); 



\Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandlerCompatible( 

    'main', 

    'OnBeforeEventAdd', 

    '\Partner\SendPassword::onBeforeEventAdd'

); 



class SendPassword 

{

    function onBeforeUserChangePassword($arParams)

    {

        self::singleton(true,$arParams["PASSWORD"]);

    }

    

    function onBeforeEventAdd(&$event, &$lid, &$arFields, &$message_id, &$files)

    {

        if($event=="USER_PASS_CHANGED")

            $arFields["PASSWORD"] = self::singleton();

    }

    

    private function singleton($write=false,$newValue=false)

    {

        static $value;

        if($write)

            $value = $newValue;

        return $value;

    }

}
```

Comment: Что то запутанно, события смены пароля и прочее непонятно зачем. Но если Вы хотите именно посылать пароль в письме, то нужно в функции обрабатывающей кнопку восстановить пароль, сделать следующее, сгенерировать пароль и запомнить, найти пользователя по емейлу или что у Вас, обновить пароль у нужного пользователя на тот что сгенерировали и отправить в письме этот же пароль (указанному емайлу/пользователю). (Лучше вместо отправки пароля отправлять ссылку но это про другое). Ну и перед отправкой и сменой, лучше сверить введённые данные, может капчу поставить для безопасности.

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос решил. В коде  не было никакого namespace Partner, если мы его не определяем то и в событиях он не нужен.